# Exception is : java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

Select data from sql database through Java code.

```
String sql="SELECT [IRB#] AS IRB_NUMBER, [RefNum] AS STUDY_PK FROM CyberProtocol1 WHERE   VelosRequestID = '"+currentRequest+"' AND TranscationStatus = 1";
    ResultSet resultSet=executeQuery(sql);

   public ResultSet executeQuery(String SQLString) {
    logDebugInfo("In executeQuery() function",LOG_TYPE_INFORMATIVE);
    ResultSet sqlResultSet = null;
    try {
        logDebugInfo("SQLString:: " + SQLString,LOG_TYPE_CRITICAL);
        executeStatement=gConn.prepareStatement(SQLString);
        sqlResultSet=executeStatement.executeQuery();
        return sqlResultSet;
    } catch (Exception errorException) {
        processException(errorException, false);
    }
    return sqlResultSet;
}
```

And get Exception is : java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: The error code makes me think you're talking to an Oracle server, yet you tag the question SQLServer?

Comment: @fvu for Oracle database code is working. Now move in sql server and sql server is new for me.

Comment: Could it be that you forgot to adapt your connection string?  `ORA-` error codes are as far as I know ***not*** generated by SQLServer, so this suggest that although you may think differently, you're  connected to an Oracle server...  And that Oracle server might be very confused by the `[]`

Comment: @fvu you are right. there is problem in connection parameters...

Comment: Missing such obvious things happens to all of us, all the time.  It might just indicate that it's time for a coffee break, or for a short walk.

Comment: While you're at it, go ahead and switch to using parameterized queries, too.